# fullpage.js + iscroll.js libraries not working corectly only on iphones

Tags: javascript, css, iscroll

It seems that fullpage.js can't detect the height of the browser on iphone devices. Any tips how to fix this? It works ok on android devices.

Here is the url:

vinarijapantic.com/apps/onePage/

Comment: I got response from Alvaro, the developer of fullpage.js that iscroll is not yet supported.